# Unable to access project API in Django in tutorial

Tags: django

I was going through this tutorial in order to learn how Django works:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Now, when I get to the part where you execute `python manage.py shell`, I enter the shell and try to run the different commands, I get this:

`>>> Poll.objects.all()

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "\", line 1, in \

NameError: name 'Poll' is not defined`

What am I doing wrong?  I re-ran the previous steps as best I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kamyar is almost right, if you received this error you probably missed the first line of the code, which is

```
>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice # Import the model classes we just wrote.
```

so do that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

You should have imported Poll with `from polls.models import Poll`

Comment: I did. Still no go.

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice
>>> import datetime
>>> Poll.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 69, in __
repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 84, in __
len__
    self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",